# Ransack Select with two options: true OR null/false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am trying to make a ransack search form that has a select box for a boolean field in my database. I want the select to have two options:

OPTION 1 - value in field matches TRUE
OPTION 2 - value in field matches FALSE or is NULL

I have tried almost every predicate and combination including field_eq, field_present, field_blank, field_in, etc but have not been able to figure out how to build such a filter in the search form. I scoured stackoverflow as well and could not find any answers. Is it possible? If not, what might be the closest alternative?

Comment: Why does this boolean field allow NULLs at all? NULL in a boolean field seems odd to me. You could make the boolean `not null default false` (or `not null default 0` if your database doesn't have a real boolean type) and the problem goes way. I only allow NULLs when I have good reasons for it.